# Getting the value of a SELECT element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that user should select start and end time of an event (only hour and minute). I want to validate the form in such a way that start time of course should be smaller than end time.

For this I have some select elements like this:

```
<select name="start_timeHour">
  <option value="00">00</option>
  <option value="01">01</option>
  <option value="02">02</option>
  <option value="03">03</option>
  <!-- UP TO 24 -->
</select>

<select name="start_timeMinutes">
.....
<select name="end_timeHour">
.....
<select name="end_timeMinutes">
<!-- I think you got the idea! -->
```

So I want to get the value of selected options for start and end (hours and minutes and compare them in an if statement). To start the things, I tried to get the value of **start_timeHour** but the alert function only shows **undefined**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateTime()
    {
        var startHour = 
            document.forms["add_new_schedule"]["start_timeHour"].value;
        alert("Start hour is ".startHour );
    }
</script>
```

Can you tell me what is the problem and how can I manage this?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript?rq=1

Comment: This question is too localized as it is about a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is correct, your mistake is in

```
alert("Start hour is ".startHour );
```

You're getting startHour property from "Start hour is" String which is undefined.

```
alert("Start hour is "+startHour );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function validateTime()
{
    var startHour = document.getElementByName('start_timeHour');
    alert("Start hour is " + startHour.options[startHour.selectedIndex].value);
}
```